# what could "above" mean here?

Tags: adverbs

> A long heavy chain connected the steel ball to a ship ***above***.

Would you possibly show me what the bold part would mean?

It could be useful if someone could teach me it through an image.

Comment: The dictionary defines "above" as "in or to a higher position than something else". I don't understand the source of your confusion. Are you having trouble understanding which thing in the sentence is above something else?

Answer (score 6):

This can be understood by adding a few words that are implied:

> A long heavy chain connected the steel ball to a ship [that was] above [the steel ball].

Since you asked for an image, there is one below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Above means at a higher position or place. In your case, it may be that there's a steel ball underwater which is connected to a (floating) ship.

Consider this example, easier to understand :

> The plane was flying above the clouds.

*Over* could also be used in this sentence. But keep in mind that *above* and *over* are **not** always synonyms.

*Over* means also that two objects are touching, whereas *above* does **not** have such connotation.

Thus, it is correct to say:

> He wore a coat *over* his suit.

But the following sentence is **wrong**:

> He wore a coat *above* his suit.

Comment: I like it so far, but I think it can get even more complex than that - ending up with the speaker needing to know almost by instinct when each could be used. A boat can sail over the ocean; a plane can fly over the ocean. 'Over' in those cases implying 'starting from one side & ending up at the other'… more akin to 'across'. On the other hand, a plane flew above the ocean indicates 'how high' rather than 'how far' - a boat would struggle with that one ;)

Comment: [*There'll Be Bluebirds **Over** The White Cliffs of Dover*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28There%27ll_Be_Bluebirds_Over%29_The_White_Cliffs_of_Dover), doesn't imply the birds will be *touching* the cliffs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly. As I wrote, one can use over instead of above, but not always vice versa.

Comment: Okay, *Queen Victoria ruled over a vast empire*. I'm not sure how generally your "definition" applies, but at the very least you should be saying *"over" **can** also mean that two objects are touching*.

Comment: Please note that my answer refers to the given question. Above and over share the definition I wrote: "at a higher position or place". Of course they have other meanings, but in this context I think it is relevant to remark that _"over" can also mean that two objects are touching_ . I did not make this last point as clear as you did, though... so thanks ;)

Comment: Perhaps this answer would be clearer if it didn't mention the word "over". Sometimes comparing and contrasting what a question asks about with something else sheds a lot of light on the former, but each English preposition is such a can of worms, it might backfire in this case.